# Odoo carry binary field to another field using create method

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

I want to create new record with create method.

This is my code:

[image]

The red line containes binary fields. Project Report fields are empty after running the function. How can i carry binary field to another field?

Comment: first check values are coming in there `self` fields or not

Comment: they are self values there